# For a system to be onto, does the pivot entry have to be all ones? And does the system have to be consistent?

Tags: linear-algebra

So, if I'm given just a matrix A. Do I have to make it into reduced row echelon form and see if all the pivot entries are 1 and that there is a pivot entry in every row to see if it is onto? Or can I just use gaussian elimination and see if there is a pivot(which is not necessarily a 1) for every row and stop there?

Also, when determining if it is onto in this way, can I just leave the b column out or is it expected to row reduce the undefined b?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

"Onto" is a property of functions, not of matrices. I'll assume that what you are asking is:

Given a matrix $A$, what do you have to do to determine whether for every vector $b$ (of the appropriate number of components) there is a solution of $Ax=b$?

You are correct that it suffices to do enough elimination to see that there is a pivot in each row. You don't need to carry along a $b$ column to do this.